# Sitecore Base Template

Tags: sitecore

I have template (A) and template (B).

B template has base template (A). But, if I update layout presentation in template (A)'s standard values, it doesn't effect on template (B)'s standard values.

Why???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue to do with the way the layout is stored in the standard values. As soon as you change the presentation details of template(B) Sitecore will copy the __renderings field value from template(A). Standard values unfortunately store the full definition of the layout, not just the change deltas like regular items and so the link is broken for the layout details between the 2 templates.

You can write a Item Saving event handler to "copy up" the calculate the differences and apply those. You can find more info and code in this blog post by Przemek Taront:

[Complex layouts in Sitecore using standard values hierarchy](https://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/complex-layouts-in-sitecore-using-standard-values-hierarchy/#.VPncP_msVqU)

Answer (score 0):

You need to click Reset under Layout ribbon on Template B's standard values.